# ArrayList output to JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, output

Yes I've googled, Yes I've read, Yes I'm still stuck...

I have an ArrayList of objects in ClassB that I'm returning to an ArrayList of objects in ClassA by calling a method from A that's in B. (Same return type: )  In CLassB, I do all the processing and storage of the object attributes into an Array of objects of the class type.

ClassB:

```
ClassB object = new ClassB();
ArrayList<ClassB> arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
while(count<10){
   ///alot going on here but the general concept is this;
  object.attribute1 = "something read in"
  object.attribute2 = "something read in"
  object.attribute3 = "something read in"
  object.attribute4 = "something read in"
  object.attribute5 = "something read in"   

  arrayOfObjects.add(object);
  count++;  

}
```

ClassA:

```
ArrayList<ClassB> arrayOfObjects = ClassBObject.method();



String[] columns = {"Column1","Column2","Column3", "Column4", "Column5"};

      DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

      JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

      int i = 0;
      while(i < arrayOfObjects.size()) {

         //v for variable       
         String v1 = arrayOfObjects .get(i).attribute1;
         String v2 = arrayOfObjects .get(i).attribute2;
         String v3 = arrayOfObjects .get(i).attribute3;
         String v4 = arrayOfObjects .get(i).attribute4;
         String v5 = arrayOfObjects .get(i).attribute5;

         Object[] row = {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5};

         tableModel.addRow(row);
         i++;
      }
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title of Table");

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

            panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Issue: With the above code, the table only displays the last object which is repeated as many times as the while loop executes. I'd like to extract the attributes from each object from the array of objects where the counter is used to match the element of the array of objects.

I hope I was detailed enough to provide enough background to get to the root of the problem.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question has *nothing* to do with JTable or Swing and all to do with your re-using an object or using static fields somewhere in your code. Time to put your debugging hat on and search for the culprit.

Comment: Have you gone through your array list with a for loop and println'd all the elements? This is basic debugging 101. It looks like you have a bug in code not shown.

Comment: I'm 3 months into my first Java class, sorry if I didn't tag this correctly.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with tagging. You are asking the wrong question. You must isolate your bug first, else you risk showing nothing relevant to the problem. I really don't think that any of the code you've posted is relevant. But rather than discuss this, you should be debugging right now. Use a debugger, use println's, isolate the error.

Comment: I've used println's in ClassB through the building of all the objects.  Then I used println(arrayOfObjects.size()) in ClassA to insure it showed up.  Short of using a println in the while loop above (which JTable does for me) I don't know where else to check.  Thats how and why I posted the code I did.  Is there something else you'd reccomend?

Comment: Yes, don't assume anything. I would still print those 5 Strings inside the while loop above.

Comment: Ok Hover, I've edited the OP to reflect how i'm adding elements to my object and then my object to an array of objects.  The above is overly simplified and pseudo code in alot of ways but the objective here is to identify where I'm going wrong.  This site is for reaching out for help so YOUR HELP and not YOUR CRITICISM is appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to give help, but please understand the criticism is there for a reason. It's not to criticize you personally, but yes, to criticize your question. Seriously, it was unanswerable when you posted it because you needed to do basic debugging first. ***NOW*** it's answerable. Thank you. Remember to try to divide and conquer -- to try to test each module of your code in isolation before joining it all together as a whole, else you'll have a monster debugging problem later.

Comment: thanks this: "Remember to try to divide and conquer -- to try to test each module of your code in isolation before joining it all together as a whole, else you'll have a monster debugging problem later."  is the biggest take away from this assignment.  I have 2 weeks of my free time invested in this assignment and that comment sums it all up!  Onto the next one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now we see your problem (possibly)!

```
ClassB object = new ClassB();
ArrayList<ClassB> arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
while(count<10){
   ///alot going on here but the general concept is this;
  object.attribute1 = "something read in"
  object.attribute2 = "something read in"
  object.attribute3 = "something read in"
  object.attribute4 = "something read in"
  object.attribute5 = "something read in"   

  arrayOfObjects.add(object);
  count++;  
}
```

You don't recreate a new object each time in the loop!

Instead try:

```
// ***** don't create object *once* outside of the while loop!
//  ClassB object = new ClassB();

ArrayList<ClassB> arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
while(count<10){

   // *** instead create a new one for each iteration of the loop!
   ClassB object = new ClassB(); // *****************

   ///alot going on here but the general concept is this;
  object.attribute1 = "something read in"
  object.attribute2 = "something read in"
  object.attribute3 = "something read in"
  object.attribute4 = "something read in"
  object.attribute5 = "something read in"   

  arrayOfObjects.add(object);
  count++;  
}
```

Comment: boom!  Thanks man!!  I've literally been troubleshooting the good part of the evening on this!!!  One helluva assignment, I wish I could share it but I need to have it graded first and we promised not to post actual code, just small samples using different nomenclature if we got stuck.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @PadawanDeveloper: you're welcome. I'm very glad this reached a happy resolution!